# Number of feature streams in mixture_weights file differs from the configured value

Tags: cmusphinx

My task is create voice recognition of Russian words list. that's why I need to use Russian acoustic model. For best recognition result, I working on acoustic model adapting.
I follow documentation [link](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt) , all seems good but when i run script :

```
./bw \
-hmmdir model \
-moddeffn model/mdef.txt 
-ts2cbfn .ptm. \
-feat 1s_c_d_dd \
-svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
-cmn current \
-agc none \
-dictfn zero_ru.dic \
-ctlfn lesniki.fields \
-lsnfn lesniki.transcription\
-accumdir .
```

I get next Errors:

```
INFO: s3mixw_Io.c(117): Read model/mixture_weights [4159x1x63 array]
FATAL: "mod_In.c", line 358: Number of feature streams in 
mixture_weights file 1 differs from the configured value 3, check the 
command line options
```

There is my projects and some links
[project on git](https://github.com/3lolo/acoustic_model-.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that configuration parameters used for `bw` are mismatched with configuration parameter the model was trained with. From the file it seems you are using `mixture weights` from continuous model, but you are trying to adapt like ptm model. For continuous models you do not need `-svspec` option but you need `-lda feature_transform` option instead. And `-ts2cbfn` must be `.cont.`, not `.ptm.`.

If you tried to adapt continuous model, you need to change parameters accordingly. Otherwise, you took `mixture_weights` file from the wrong model.

Comment: how can i get a mixture_weights file for custom acoustic model

Comment: You can retrain model

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev: I had same problem and tried what you said but it gave me this error message:   `ERROR: "cmd_ln.c", line 607: Unknown argument name 'feature_transform' `

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev: This is the command I use `
./bw -hmmdir en-us -moddeffn en-us/mdef.txt -ts2cbfn .cont. -feat 1s_c_d_dd -cmn current -agc none -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict -ctlfn robot_train.fileids -lsnfn robot_train.transcription -accumdir -lda feature_transform . ` and I got the model from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-5.2.tar.gz/download

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev: please check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453344/how-should-i-set-bw-options-for-acoustic-model-adaption