# How should I set "bw" options for acoustic model adaption?

Tags: pocketsphinx, acoustics, adaption

In tutorials it has written this command:
~~~

```
./bw \
 -hmmdir en-us \
 -moddeffn en-us/mdef.txt \
 -ts2cbfn .ptm. \
 -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
 -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
 -cmn current \
 -agc none \
 -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict \
 -ctlfn arctic20.fileids \
 -lsnfn arctic20.transcription \
 -accumdir .
~~~
```

But I checked my `feat.params` and it has this content:

```
~~~
-lowerf 130
-upperf 6800
-nfilt 25
-transform dct
-lifter 22
-feat 1s_c_d_dd
-svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38
-agc none
-cmn current
-varnorm no
-model ptm
-cmninit 40,3,-1
~~~
```

I don't know how should I config these options? I am trying to config acoustic model for contunuous speaking.

I got my model from here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-5.2.tar.gz/download

And tried to configure the above command like this:

```
./bw -hmmdir en-us -moddeffn en-us/mdef.txt -ts2cbfn .cont. -feat 1s_c_d_dd -cmn current -agc none -dictfn cmudict-en-us.dict -ctlfn robot_train.fileids -lsnfn robot_train.transcription -accumdir -lda feature_transform .
```

But I get these error messages:

> INFO: main.c(229): Compiled on Mar 22 2018 at 12:54:02 ERROR:
>   "cmd_ln.c", line 607: Unknown argument name 'feature_transform' ERROR:
>   "cmd_ln.c", line 704: Failed to parse arguments list ERROR:
>   "cmd_ln.c", line 753: Failed to parse arguments list, forced exit

Comment: don't get confused between continuous speech recognition and continuous acoustic model. you have downloaded ptm model hence the command given in the tutorial will work. else download continuous model and then try your command.

Comment: @G10DRAS I have downloaded this model : https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/cmusphinx-en-us-5.2.tar.gz/download , but it gives me the same error!

Comment: @G10DRAS: may you give me the download link of the true model?

Comment: look at your command for error, i see minor mistakes in it. correct it and run again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my model to this file (from the `ptm` model that tutorial linked to it) : https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/cmusphinx-en-us-5.2.tar.gz/download

Then I removed the `-lda feature_transform` from my command, and it worked!

Comment: instead of writing Q&A yourself, consider deleting this question from StackOverflow.

Comment: You did answer your own question,  but still you didn't figure out the exact problem with your command.